# NoClassDefFoundError at Run time

Tags: java, jboss

I used `Apache POI` library in my application and uploaded into `JBoss AS 7.1`  . It deployed the jar successfully and I was able to run the application with out any errors/exceptions, Where as the same jar if i deploy into `jboss-5.0.1.GA`. It is throwing the following exception.

```
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:154)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:54)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:82)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:267)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:120)
...

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:738)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$100(ModuleImpl.java:60)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1650)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
... 19 more
```

If i add `dom4j` jar. It throws a new Exception that is

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
```

What would be the problem? Does `JBoss5` load classes differently from `JBoss7` ? What I am missing here?

Note: My application is a standalone java application

Comment: The apparently ridiculous `ClassCastException` is a sure indication that you have the same class being loaded by two different class loaders.  When this happens, the classes have the same fully-qualified name but are not compatible as far as the JVM is concerned.  It is likely JBOSS loads an older dom4j that does not define `DocumentException`.

Comment: What could be the work around @JimGarrison

Comment: It's been awhile since I had to debug classloader issues, and it's never an enjoyable task.  See if JBOSS has a way to put your dom4j in the classpath for your application instead of a global classpath.

Comment: @JimGarrison I Compiled my project with jdk1.5 and the target is jdk 1.6. would this be an issue?

Comment: How is your "stand-alone Java application" loaded into JBoss?

Comment: I make my standalone application as a jar file and I deploy into an existing EAR application. @Beryllium

Comment: Its basically runs as a plugin in BPM tool @Beryllium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you could try to remove the classpath JRE in your eclipse, re-add JRE to your `buildpath` and restart the eclipse and make sure your java compiler is 6. And deploy your `osgi plugin`. and restart the JBoss.

**Note:** before you deploy the `osgi plugin` clear the `osgi-cache`.